# what does the Select method do on a c# int array

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner at C#.

I have come across this piece of code:

```
List<RelatedProductViewModel> relatedProductViewModel = vm.RelatedProductID.Select(p => new RelatedProductViewModel { RelatedProductID = p, ProductID = vm.ProductID, Type = vm.Type }).ToList();
```

vm.RelatedProductID is an int array with just one element (0) with a value of 8666.

So I'm thinking that Select is a method available on int arrays, but I can't find any documentation on this.

Can anybody enlighten me:

What does Select do?

Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out what value is being used for p in the llambda expression - please don't get too technical about llambda expression as I have only just read about them.

Comment: [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

Comment: It's an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` sitting in the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: It is a Linq extension method, it works on any collection that implements IEnumerable<>.  Like arrays.  Lots and lots of resources available that explain Linq.

Comment: Thank you - so how do I go about discovering whether a method belongs to the object in hand or to some other underlying object?  I seem to waste a lot of time hunting for things in the wrong places.

Comment: @Graham: You are using Linq expressions here, so anything you do with enumerable types will have lots more methods, like `Where()`, `GroupBy()` etc. If you want to find out where it is located, just highlight it and press F1 in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select is part of `IEnumerable<T>`. Arrays automatically implement `IEnumerable<T>` when they are created, so since it implements it, the .Select() is available from there.

But Select is *projecting* the results from one set to another. It is returning 1 result per iterated value.

When using .Select on an `IQueryable<T>`, internally it may work slightly differently. It retrieves them as they are iterated, much like a `yield` does.

By using `ToList()` at the end, you are forcing it to enumerate all results in one go. For in memory types this is quick, but for databases or resources that have a latency in retrieving items, this can have a large performance impact.

Comment: It's not technically "part of `IEnumerable<T>`" since interfaces don't have method definitions; it's actually an [*extension method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @DanPuzey: Thanks for clarifying, I will leave the answer intact, so other readers can learn from your comment.

Comment: _When using .Select on an IQueryable<T>, internally it may work slightly differently. It retrieves them as they are iterated, much like a yield does._ is not really true. Iterating `IEnumerable<T>` also retrieves elements as they are iterated. The difference is that `IQueryable<T>` provides a mechanism for "moving" the projection or filter back to the source. This allows LINQ statements to be converted to e.g. SQL and evaluted on the database server for much better performance.

Answer (score 6):

`Select` creates a projection; meaning, you provide a function that takes an `int` and outputs a *something*, then for every `int` in the array it executes the function. It is basically this:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource,TResult>(
      this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,TResult> selector)
{
    foreach(TSource item in source)
        yield return selector(source);
}
```

In your case, the selector for each is:

```
p => new RelatedProductViewModel { RelatedProductID = p,
                 ProductID = vm.ProductID, Type = vm.Type }
```

Meaning: each value `p` in the array become the `RelatedProductID` of a new `RelatedProductViewModel`, with a `ProductID` and `Type` set via the "captured" value of `vm`.

So the output in your example will be a list of length 1, where that single item has a `RelatedProductID` of 8666.

Answer (score 2):

The code is equivalent (but not exactly the same as the following code):

```
List<RelatedProductViewModel> relatedProductViewModel
  = new List<RelatedProductViewModel>();
foreach (var p in vm.RelatedProductID) {
  relatedProductViewModel.Add(
    new RelatedProductViewModel {
      RelatedProductID = p,
      ProductID = vm.ProductID,
      Type = vm.Type
    }
  );
}
```

The `Select` **projects** the items in the source sequence (`relatedProductViewModel`) into a new sequence of elements. The projected sequence is then converted to a list by `ToList()` and stored in `relatedProductViewModel`.

As you can see, using LINQ (the original code) creates much cleaner code.